# Exibir div em outro lugar, de acordo com a resolução de tela

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Teria como eu dar um include diferente para cada resolução? Tipo...

se a resolução(largura) for maior que 768 eu quero exibir 2 colunas(grid_6 e grid_6), abrindo o texto ao lado, ok.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas se for uma resolução menos, quero exibir apenas uma coluna(grid_12) abrindo o texto abaixo de cada elemento clicado, e não ao final de tudo como ocorre no momento.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como posso fazer isso?
obs: cada elemento do funil é uma div separada com a imagem.

segue meu codigo:

```
<script>
    function funil(el){
        $('#img_funil_1').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(70%)");
        $('#img_funil_2').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(70%)");
        $('#img_funil_3').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(70%)");
        $('#img_funil_4').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(70%)");
        $("#img_"+el.id).css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(0%)");
        $('#funil_1').hide();
        $('#funil_2').hide();
        $('#funil_3').hide();
        $('#funil_4').hide();
        $(el).fadeIn(500);
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        funil(funil_1);
    }
</script>

<div class="post-area grid_6">
    <div class="posts-container funil">
       <div class="funil_1"><a id="img_funil_1" onclick="funil(funil_1)"><img src="images/funil/1atrair_visitantes.png"></a></div>
       <div class="funil_2"><a id="img_funil_2" onclick="funil(funil_2)"><img src="images/funil/2converter_oportunidades.png"></a></div>
       <div class="funil_3"><a id="img_funil_3" onclick="funil(funil_3)"><img src="images/funil/3fechar_clientes.png"></a></div>
       <div class="funil_4"><a id="img_funil_4" onclick="funil(funil_4)"><img src="images/funil/4fidelizar_clientes.png"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-area grid_6">
    <div class="posts-container">
        <div id="funil_1">
            <p>
            atrair visitantes atrair visitantes atrair...
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="funil_2">
            <p>
            converter oportunidades converter oportunidades...
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="funil_3">
            <p>
            fechar clientes fechar clientes fechar clientes...
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="funil_4">
            <p>
            fidelizar clientes fidelizar clientes fidelizar...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

de forma bem grosseira, quero q isso aconteça quando a resolução for inferior a 768:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @media queries.

Exemplo:

.grid6 {
  width:50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .grid6 {
   width:100%;
 }
}

Se a resolção for menor que 768px a div ocupara toda a linha, senão somente metade.

Comment: isso de certa forma ja acontece, oque eu preciso é que o conteudo mude de lugar tambem, indo para baixo da imagem a qual pertence.

Comment: Então coloque um float:left também. E você tentou o exemplo que mostrei? Uso muito ele, veja nesse projeto que fiz http://www.engatevolpato.com.br/novo/index.asp, na parte la em baixo onde diz lançamentos, cada item cada produto daqueles seriam os seus .grid6, com 50% de tamanho(e é claro com paddings e margins), ao redimensionar o navegador eles ficam com tamanho 100%.

Comment: não tentei, pois a estrutura do meu é bem diferente. de um lado tenho diversas divs empilhadas, e do outro apenas uma(visivel) com a altura maior, para todo o texto explicativo. eu entendi como funciona o seu projeto, mas essa solução não se aplica ao meu, a menos que sugira uma alteração na estrutura. Desculpe se entendi errado

Comment: kkkk Eu ainda cismo que vai funcionar kkk, não teria uma pagina de teste pra mim dar uma olhada.

Comment: Nesse exemplo da pra entender melhor http://www.amasterpanfletagem.com.br/novo/ embaixo do banner tem dois cards(que seriam suas duas divs .grid6) ao redimensionar, a que está do lado direito vai para baixo da que está do lado esquerdo, a diferença é que no meu eu coloquei um margin neles para não ficarem muito juntos.

Comment: entendi, vou tentar aqui. não tenho um exemplo online no momento.

Comment: Qualquer coisa poste o css da classe .grid6 também.

Comment: consegui, não ficou exatamente como eu tinha em mente, mas funcionou bem. obrigado